# CasperJS waitForSelector works but querySelector null

Tags: javascript, phantomjs, casperjs

I'm working with CasperJS and I can get a "success" from waitForSelector but when i try to do document.querySelector for the same selector - it returns null?

My code

```
"use strict";
var casper = require('casper').create({
    verbose: false,
    logLevel: 'warning',
    waitTimeout: 10000
});
phantom.cookiesEnabled = true;

var x = require('casper').selectXPath;
casper.options.viewportSize = {width: 1920, height: 965};
casper.on('page.error', function(msg, trace) {
   this.echo('Error: ' + msg, 'ERROR');
   for(var i=0; i<trace.length; i++) {
       var step = trace[i];
       this.echo('   ' + step.file + ' (line ' + step.line + ')', 'ERROR');
   }
});

var selector = ".table-component";
casper.waitForSelector(selector,
    function success() {
        console.log("table found");
        console.log(document.querySelector(selector));      
    },
    function fail() {
        console.log("oops");
    }
);
casper.run();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PhantomJS has two contexts and since CasperJS is built on top of PhantomJS, it inherits this fact.

You can only access the DOM through [`casper.evaluate()`](http://docs.casperjs.org/en/latest/modules/casper.html#evaluate) (wrapper around [`page.evaluate()`](http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/method/evaluate.html)). All CasperJS functions that take selectors as arguments, use `evaluate()` internally. Note that `evaluate()` is sandboxed and you can only pass primitive types in and out of it. DOM elements are not primitive types, so you cannot pass them out of the page (DOM) context. You will have to pass some kind of *representation* of the information that you want as primitive types:

```
casper.waitForSelector(selector,
    function success() {
        this.echo("table found");
        this.echo("1: "+this.evaluate(function(sel){
            return !!document.querySelector(sel)
        }, selector));
        this.echo("2: "+this.evaluate(function(sel){
            return document.querySelector(sel).textContent;
        }, selector));
    },
    function fail() {
        console.log("oops");
    }
);
```

I suggest that you look into the other helpful functions such as [`casper.getElementInfo()`](http://docs.casperjs.org/en/latest/modules/casper.html#getelementinfo).

Answer (score 2):

`document.querySelector` in CasperJs works in DOM context. To use any DOM request use the `casper.evaluate()` or `this.evaluate`. Also the variables declared outside the scope of evaluate function need to be passed in a certain manner as shown below.

```
var selector = ".table-component";
casper.waitForSelector(selector,
    function success() {
        console.log("table found");
        var temp=this.evaluate(function(slctr){
            return document.querySelector(selector);
        },selector);
        console.log(temp);
    },
    function fail() {
        console.log("oops");
    }
);
```